# swift Firestore 'absl/numeric/int128_have_intrinsic.inc' file not found

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, abseil

I just recently installed an extension to Firebase called Trigger Email which uses a Cloud Firestore Collection. I was trying to Firestore to my iOS project to use it, and got the following error:

```
'absl/numeric/int128_have_intrinsic.inc' file not found
```

[Error in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOwkq.png)

Here are the contents of my podfile as well:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'FRC Lookout' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for FRC Lookout

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'


pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5.7'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SpreadsheetView'
pod 'CollapsibleTableSectionViewController', '~> 2.0.1'
pod 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 7.0'
pod 'PageControls'
pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
end
```

It also looks like the [file does exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyh4V.png), but either the wrong path or something.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: hi, i think your pods are outdated please update your cocoapods by running installing command or run "pods update" to update pod file.

Comment: I've got the same issue, did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work finally after doing a

```
pod deintegrate
```

then redoing my

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

So I have the same issue as you are having. Well different Pods of course. Did some research...

I've notice when updating or installing Pods, there was a message that says there is an update for CocoaPods. (Just now it's 1.8.4)

So I ran the command > **gem install cocoapods**

after everything was updated, my project can compile!

I hope this can work for ya and same with everyone else...

Answer (score 2):

For me the other answer did not work. There's also another piece to the puzzle as with the [Version 6.13.0 - November 14, 2019](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_6130_-_november_14_2019) release we see this note

> Removed Firestore's dependency on the Protobuf CocoaPod. If you're
>   manually tracking dependencies, you may be able to remove it from your
>   build (note, however, that other Firebase components may still require
>   it).
>
> Added a dependency on the abseil CocoaPod. If you're manually tracking
>   dependencies, you need to add it to your build.

So even after updating etc, I had the same error as the OP. To correct that, I removed CocoaPods from my project by quitting XCode and then using the cocoapods app. File->Remove Cocoapods from a project.

I then dropped into terminal an updated cocoapods manually

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and then navigated to the project folder and then

```
pod install
```

to reinstall updated pods in the project. Then when running the project the OP's error was resolved but I was left with

```
Framework not found Protobuf
```

so there was some reference to protobuf hanging around. In the project I went to

```
Target->Build Settings
```

and using the find field, search for Protobuf which should find it in the Other Linker Flags.

In the Other Linker Flags option, you may see a highlighted section in the middle of that line. Double click to open those frameworks in a popup window and scroll down the list until you find

```
-framework
"protobuf"
```

Select those two lines, hit the minus sign at the bottom of that popup window to delete that link, clean and rebuild.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the pod files from the project and all files related to pods. Then installed once more in the same project folder and compiled. This worked for me. Used pods with its version number
Ex:

> pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.1.0' 
>   pod 'Firebase/Auth', '6.1.0' 
>   pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '6.1.0' 
>   pod 'Firebase/Storage', '6.1.0' 
>   pod 'Firebase/Functions', '6.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this error is to go into your podfile and remove firebase firestore. Then check that you have completed setting up your database on the firebase website. After removing firebase firestore run pod install. This will remove Firebase Firestore. Then go back in to your podfile and re-add Firebase Firestore. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

As some others have mentioned the correct answer is to use an updated version of cocoapods.
To check the version of cocoapods use `pod --version`.
If you see `1.5.0` you need to be on a higher version such as `1.8.4`.

`sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4`

If after installation you are still not seeing an updated version when you do `pod --version` then you could be running the wrong `pod` file.
You'd need to correct that in your `~/.bash_profile`.

You can type `pod env` to see more info about the pod file.

The executable pod that I use is in `~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/pod`.

---

Side note. If you have openssl errors you can use one of the following commands.

### Use version 1.0.0 (most likely will need this)

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

### Upgrade to the latest

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a cocoapods environment bug.

To fix it, completely uninstall and reinstall cocoapods.

1)

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate
gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

2)

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

3)

```
pod install
```

Comment: You need to give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer